# python sqlalchemy create bigquery table with partition

Tags: python, google-bigquery, sqlalchemy

How can I using sqlalchemy to create a table with partition.
I already read the docs:

- [google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#sql) - only support create table with partition using python using lib `google.cloud`
- [sqlalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html) - only docs for psql, oracle and mysql, ... except big query
- [python-bigquery-sqlalchemy](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-sqlalchemy) - this is just a readme, not documentation.

Do any body using sqlalchemy big query to create table with partition, I have no idea for which is passed to `__table_args__` in class model to create table with partition?